# Google App Script FORMS delete and add choices in listItem

Tags: google-apps-script

I need a form with a listitem that pulls the data from a spreadsheet. Done that, works fine. The problem is I need to update that listitem when i update the spreadsheet data, so I created a script in the form that imports the data from the spreadsheet everytime I open the form.

I don't know how to change the listitem values. I can delete the listitem and create it again with the new data but it writes the results in another column, so I have the deleted old one in blank and a new one with data, and this happens everytime.

How can I modify the choices in a listitem?

```
    function makeOptionClient() {

  var formulari = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);


  //Delete form Items
  var itemsFormulari = formulari.getItems().length;
  while(formulari.getItems().length!=0){        
    try{      
     formulari.deleteItem(0);
     } catch(error)
     {Logger.log(error);
     }
  }


 //Import Clients List
  var range = ss.getRangeByName("Clients");
  var values = range.getValues();
  Logger.log(values);

  var item = formulari.addListItem();
  item.setTitle("Client");
  item.setChoiceValues(values);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A form is build with items of different kind, each item has a specific type and an ID.
Once you have this item you can manipulate its content the way you want...if it's a text, change the text, if it's a list, remove and add elements from / to this list.

The script you tried does not go deep enough, you are only finding form items, in this case the list itself and try to delete it.  What you need is to go one level further and remove the elements from the list.

The [doc shows different methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form) to get form element and the object it returns... including a link to the methods you can apply to this object. The method pointed by the above link gets elements by type, I think it's the most appropriate for your use case.

Nothing very complex actually, documentation is pretty clear.